# Android Several Hotspots Connection

Tags: wifi-hotspot

It is possible to connect to several Android HotSpots at the same time ?

Comment: Might wanna edit out the 2nd part of the question, as dev stuff is off-topic here. The question itself sounds alright to me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect your android to two wireless connection at a time, as of now. You can do so in your PC or Mac using USB WiFi Adapter.

But if you have mobile internet and a WiFi connection, you can combine both using an app called VideoBee. But as the name suggests, this app is only meant for streaming videos. Learn more about VideoBee [here](https://apkpure.com/videobee-stream-download/sw.videob)

Hope this helps.